# Sqlite игнорировать регистр в условии WHERE

Tags: android, кириллица, sqlite, sql

Подскажите как на андроиде в sqlite базе сделать выборку на кирилице, игнорируя регистр?
запросы с LIKE, COLLATE NOCASE и UPPER(column_name) **работают только для английских букв**! А для русских нет!
Для примера, имею таблицу favourite  с записью *title = **Т**ест*, юзер пытается запросить её но в поле поиска вводит слово ***тест*** маленькими буквами.
пробовал такие варианты:

```
SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE title LIKE '%тест%'  
SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE UPPER('%тест%')  
SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE title LIKE '%ТЕСТ%' COLLATE NOCASE
```

все три варианта не подходят,  больше ничего не нагуглил. Подскажите пожалуйста решение 
ps: запросы осуществляю так:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); //*extends SQLiteOpenHelper*  
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то это известный баг или фича (кому как) SQLite. Он не понимает case-insensitive `where/like/glob`, когда символы не в ASCII. [Как говорит мануал:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> A bug: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.)

Единственный способ обойти это ограничение, это завести хранимую процедуру выполняющую операцию сравнения.

**Update** Я слегка погорячился по поводу хранимых процедур в SQLite. SQLite не поддерживает хранимые процедуры в общепринятом смысле, нужно писать т.н. *custom function* на С, [пример здесь](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)

Comment: а можно пожалуйста пример, как это сделать?

Comment: вобщем ладно, раз такие фичи в sqlite, то сделал свой костыль: добавил в таблицу поле search_str и при добавлении новой записи в таблицу в это поле добавляю в апперкейсе строку содержащую текст всех полей: (title+text+url).toUpperCase(),и потом при поиске делаю WHERE search_str LIKE '%ИСКОМЫЙ_ТЕКСТ%'

Comment: А если строка будет типа: `ИсКоМыЙ_тЕкСт`?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ при добавлении записи в таблицу, в поле search_str попадает текст в ЗАГЛАВНОМ РЕГИСТРЕ, при поиске строки в базе я перед тем как составить запрос, перевожу ИсКоМыЙ_тЕкСт так же в .toUpperCase(). Примерно так:   
String searchText = editSearch.getText().toString.toUpperCase();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE search_str LIKE '%"+searchText +"%'"; данный способ работает нормально, проверял разными вариантами написания, единственный его минус поучается что в поле search_str  дублируется контент всей записи.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Любопытно, написание кастомных функции будь-то на [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285396/case-insensitive-utf8-select/5582015#5582015) или Ваш [пример на C](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) сильно влияет на производительность, используются ли индексы в таком случае? Ясно дело, что при такой конструкции `%ищу тебя%` - "прощай" индексы, но я о иных сценариях.

Comment: @snake223 Вы пробовали [SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction()](http://goo.gl/Z48bTf)? Документацию на неё, я так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 5):

В android такое невозможно. sqlite там собран без ICU, возможность загрузки экстеншнов отключена. Переопределить там ничего не получится, `case_sensitive_like` тоже бесполезен.

Есть несколько обходных вариантов.

1. Добавить в базу ещё одно поле *title_lc*, в котором хранить то же значение, что и в *title*, но в нижнем регистре. Преобразование производить на java при помощи `String#toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())`
2. В android sqlite есть 2 нестандартных collator'а: *LOCALIZED* и *UNICODE*. Collator указывается в определении столбца при создании БД:

   `CREATE TABLE t1(title TEXT COLLATE LOCALIZED);`

Сравнение строк будет регистронезависимым (`SELECT * where title = "ТеСт"`;) .
  Минусы: 
     * *COLLATE UNICODE* часто не работает; 
     * при использовании *COLLATE LOCALIZED* нужно указывать локаль для БД: (`SQLiteDatabase#setLocale(new Locale("ru_RU"))`);
     * и самый большой минус в том, что *LIKE* не работает.

1. Воспользоваться не родной сборкой sqlite. Например, [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) можно пересобрать вручную, включив ICU.

Answer (score 3):

Для SQLite обычно требуется выставить переменную `case_sensitive_like`

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF;
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/wWJkvL)

Можно через костыль

```
SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE '%ТЕСТ%'
```

Предварительно `тест` поднять в верхний регистр на уровне приложения `toUpperCase()`.

#### Резюме:

Для UTF-8 необходимо переопределять `LIKE`. Есть вариант, как это сделать [на PHP (через RegEx-ы)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285396/case-insensitive-utf8-select/5582015#5582015). Для Android SDK смотрите в сторону [SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction()](http://goo.gl/Z48bTf)

Comment: @romeo а это точно должно работать в sqlite? просто мне выдаёт ошибку запроса

Comment: @snake223 Что именно? Я Вам привел три варианта. Я не уверен, что `BINARY` SQLiteпонимает

Comment: @romeo первый вопрос относился к бинари, когда вы еще не изменили свой ответ. по поводу UPPER - я же написал что он не помогает, пробовал и 'тест' переводить в toUpperCase(). А как в андроиде выставить PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON; ?

Comment: @snake223

    db.execSQL("PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true;"); // true, on, yes и 1 эквивалентны

После соединения с БД, т.е.

    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...);
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true;");

Comment: выставил  case_sensitive_like  в false и опять тоже самое - английские ищутся, русские только если регистр совпадает

Comment: @snake223

**Резюме:** Необходимо переопределять `LIKE`. Есть вариант, как это сделать [на PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285396/case-insensitive-utf8-select/5582015#5582015). Для Android SDK смотрите в сторону [SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction()](http://goo.gl/Z48bTf)

Comment: Кстати, оказывается на hashcode этот [вопрос уже поднимался](http://goo.gl/6ehzW6)